# Creating an ISODate for MongoDB with PHP

Tags: php, python, mongodb, date

I did a lot of preprocessing with Python, and the [pymongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.9%2B/index.html) driver uses ISODate for it's native date / time translation. Now PHP uses the [MongoDate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php) class which give `{"sec":1296536400,"usec":0}` as my "date". Is there anyway to force PHP to use an ISODate or vice-versa with Python (and pymongo)? I need compatible dates but the native formats don't seem to want to play nice.

Comment: Can you clarify which direction you're going here? *From* Python *to* PHP or the other way around? If you're having issues between them maybe it's just best to use a date string to avoid confusion `("2011-02-22...")`

Comment: @gates: But I want to be able to make things as natively compatible with JS as possible.

Comment: What version of mongo are you using? Mongo changed to default ISODate in 1.7x

Comment: @Michael: Yes, I noticed. But `MongoDate` in PHP isn't giving me that unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDate are in [ISODate](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Data+Types+and+Conventions) and in [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php). I guess it has changed since the question.

Comment: And I've started storing everything in straight unix time for simplicity.