# comparing date with mongoDB ISODate format in php

Tags: php, mongodb, date, iso

I am having a field in mongoDB, say `birth_date` which is in ISODate format like

```
ISODate("2013-08-15T23:00:00Z")
```

In php, I am getting dates in the string format

`"2013-08-10"`

I want all the data for which `birth_date` is greater than `2013-08-10`

For this I have a code

```
$inputDate = "2013-08-10";
$dateFilter = array("\$gte",$inputDate); //works well when birth_date field is normat date string like "2013-08-16" but doesn't work with ISODate format as above
$dateRangeQuery = array("birth_date" => $dateFilter);
```

which generate the query `{"birth_date":{"$gte":"2013-08-10"}}` which is not correctly filtering data.

Following code snippet too didn't work

```
$dateFilter = array("\$gte",date("c", $inputDate));
```

generates the query

`{"birth_date":{"$gte":"2013-08-10T00:00:00+05:30"}}`

then this too didn't work

```
$dateFilter = new MongoDate($inputDate)
```

generates query

```
{"birth_date":{"$gte":{"sec":2013,"usec":0}}}
```

Please suggest :)

Comment: I viewed this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082751/creating-an-isodate-for-mongodb-with-php which is not much helpful

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct way was to use `strtotime` as in

`$dateFilter = new MongoDate(strtotime($inputDate))`

like [MongoDate class in PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php)

Answer (score 1):

There another solution  to create `mongoDate` , **just** create `DateTime` object and get timestamp using `DateTime` object then create `MongoDate` object by `timestamp`

```php
    $inputDate = new DateTime('2013-08-10');
    $mongoDate = new MongoDate($inputDate->getTimestamp());
```

In case need to use current DateTime

```php
   $currentDateTime = strtotime('now'); // as This method already ruen timestamp 
   $mongoDate = new MongoDate($currentDateTime);
```

Comment: you meant: `$currentDateWithTime = new DateTime(...);` BTW? no need to use a variable if you intend to use its value immediately after.

Comment: @FabienHaddadi Yes I made a mistake for first point(I fix it), about second point you are right especial into Real Code, But into `Stackoverflow` I believe code example must be simple to read and easy to understand.